# Priority queue not working with Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, background-process

I'm trying to use priority queues with **Celery 3.1.23** and **RabbitMQ 3.6.11** in my flask app. But the tasks are not picked up by workers based on priority. Here is my code:

#### Celery config:

```python
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', RABBITMQ_URL)
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', REDIS_URL)
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = int(os.environ.get('BROKER_POOL_LIMIT', 10))
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'non_web'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False

CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('urgent', Exchange('urgent', type='direct'), routing_key='urgent', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 8}),
    Queue('web', Exchange('web', type='direct'), routing_key='web', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 6}),
    Queue('non_web', Exchange('non_web', type='direct'), routing_key='non_web', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 4}),
    Queue('background', Exchange('background', type='direct'), routing_key='background', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 2}),
)
```

Here I want the tasks queued in `urgent` queue get higher priority. Then comes `web` and then `non_web` and at last `background` queue. But the tasks queued in `non-web` is always executed first. Here is the code for jobs.

#### Jobs:

```python
from time import sleep

@celery.task(queue='web', priority=8)
def high_priority_job():
    print 'High priority job'
    for i in range(1, 31):
        print i
        sleep(1)

@celery.task(queue='non_web', priority=6)
def medium_priority_job():
    print 'Medium priority job'
    for i in range(1, 31):
        print i
        sleep(1)
```

I tried queuing jobs in a queue like this:

```python
def queue_jobs():
    for i in range(50):
        medium_priority_job.delay()
    for i in range(20):
        high_priority_job.delay()
```

In this the high priority jobs are being executed only after all the medium priority jobs are completed. I have also tried removing priority from jobs declaration and set it while queuing the job like this:

```python
def queue_jobs():
    for i in range(50):
        medium_priority_job.apply_async(priority=6)
    for i in range(20):
        high_priority_job.apply_async(priority=8)
```

This didn't work either. I tried upgrading Celery to the latest version. That didn't help either. What is wrong here? Do I need to change any settings?

Comment: as my knowledge , the priority is within in same queue , not among different queues . So the setting will be  " CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('urgent', Exchange('urgent', type='direct'), routing_key='urgent', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 8}) ,) " , which 8 is the highest priority . you produce the task into queue "urgent" with different priority , higher is more urgent .

Answer (score 0):

Note that priority values are sorted in reverse order: 0 being highest priority as per celery official documentation.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.3.0/userguide/routing.html

In your case `medium_priority_job` will execute first because priority is 6 and next `high_priority_job` will execute which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No wonder it did not work considering that you are using different queue in each case, so they execute regularly. So to test priority usage use a single queue, and send tasks with different priority levels to it.

Also, there was confusion regarding the priority levels and what they mean when different brokers are used - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319834/could-someone-please-clarify-the-task-priority-usage-in-celery-tasks).